# Python subprocess is slowly decreasing in speed

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, subprocess

I just started with python and I have this code that iterates in any folder and goes through all videos to apply an ffmpeg command for editing.

In the first video the speed is 5x then for each video the speed decreases until 1x.

Is there anyway to fix this?

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
filename = path + '\\' + file

if file.endswith(".mp4"): 
    video_duration = mp.VideoFileClip(filename).duration

    subprocess.run('ffmpeg -i {filename} -i {img} -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay={width}:{height}:enable=\'between(t,{start_from},{end_to})\'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy {copyto}{video_name}_EDITED_{count}.mp4'.format(
        filename = filename,img = image, copyto = copy_to,video_name = file,count = count,start_from = start_from(video_duration), end_to = end_to(video_duration),
        width = auto_width(video_width), height = auto_height(video_height)))
    count = count + 1
```

[image]

Comment: Does slowdown also appear if you launch your `ffmpeg` commands manually (without python)?

Comment: @Daweo yea in some videos, but in python the first video always starts in 5x speed and then it starts to decrease, also in python when the script starts it creates almost 20 ffmpeg.exe processes in task manager